# Uninstall individual Office 2016 programs

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, uninstall, microsoft-office-2016

I installed Office Professional Plus 2016 on my windows 10 system. When I installed it, it didn't give me an option of which office programs to install, like it did in the 2010 version (ex. word, excel etc.). The only program I will use is office word. I don't want all the other programs.

Is there a way, or "hack" to get rid of all the programs besides for office word?

Comment: Is it the `preview`?

Comment: No. It's the full version

Comment: I just know, that it wasn't possible in the preview, but I think it should be possible in the full version. So it was in the earlier versions: When you have an installer, you could choose `customize`.

Comment: There is NO way if you are running a Click-To-Run version

Comment: @h0ch5tr4355 - It isn't possible; Alright it is possible it involves a hacked together solution;  The Office installer was changed with Office 2016.

Comment: That's a pity, but the programs are linked so closely that it probably became impossible for Microsoft to separate them strictly.

Comment: Can you show me the hacked solution?

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like Is there another way to install it?

Comment: @Jessica I haven't found a hacked way yet & seems quite difficult to do that as everything is streamed in this method of installation. It would have been possible if there was a MSI version but i haven't seen that either

Answer (score 12):

Seems you installed Office in Click-to-Run way, unfortunately it's not possible to select what you want to install by default

But you can try changing installation config to achieve this

As the answer in [this post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/8b76d812-d631-45b6-b60c-fb4a933d1f91/how-to-uninstall-access-2016-and-onedrive-for-business-in-office-2016-suite?forum=Office2016setupdeploy&prof=required) in Office Tech, you can add something like below in xml config to skip applications you don't want

```xml
<ExcludeApp ID= "Access" />
```

If you want only Word, then exclude all but Word in config like

```xml
<Configuration>
  <Add OfficeClientEdition="64" >
    <Product ID="ProPlusRetail">
      <Language ID="en-us"/>
      <ExcludeApp ID= "Access" />
      <ExcludeApp ID= "Lync" />
      <ExcludeApp ID= "Outlook" />
      <ExcludeApp ID= "OneDrive" />
      <ExcludeApp ID= "OneNote" />
      <ExcludeApp ID= "Groove" />
      <ExcludeApp ID= "Publisher" />
      <ExcludeApp ID= "SharePointDesigner" />
      <ExcludeApp ID= "PowerPoint" />
      <ExcludeApp ID= "Excel" />
      <ExcludeApp ID= "Visio" />
    </Product>
  </Add>
</Configuration>
```

After editing, save and run installer

Full Office product list from [Microsoft TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219426.aspx#Anchor_1)

```
ID="Access"
ID="Excel"
ID="Groove"
ID="InfoPath"
ID="Lync"
ID="OneDrive"
ID="OneNote"
ID="Outlook"
ID="PowerPoint"
ID="Publisher"
ID="SharePointDesigner"
ID="Visio"
ID="Word"
```

Comment: Its also all detailed within this Stack post which also covers where to get the Config tool, how to use it and an online Editor to build the elements of the custom configuration.xml  https://superuser.com/questions/980032/office-2016-advanced-setup/1239625

Answer (score 9):

For starters, out-of-the-box, Microsoft doesn't support individual installation of office 2016 applications. See this quote from [their blog](https://blogs.office.com/2015/10/01/your-top-questions-about-office-2016-answered/) and [this post](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Can-I-do-a-custom-install-of-individual-Office-suite-applications-1eede13d-3426-40cc-b30b-9aa40226bb9e):

> 7. Can I install a subset of the Office 2016 applications?
>
> No, the ability to selectively install individual applications is not
>   available with Office 2016. The vast majority of customers prefer the
>   full installation of all of the Office apps so they are assured that
>   they have the ability to open, view and edit any document they may
>   need. We will continue to evaluate feedback on this topic.

If you're interested in a work-around, all I've found was [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/980032/office-2016-advanced-setup), but results aren't verified. Apparently, MS is now providing administrators with a [deployment tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49117) for click-to-run installations. If you plan on trying this, I'm curious to see if it works. If it doesn't, it's still possible to supply MS with feedback concerning this, it wouldn't be the first time they change policies after massive feedback from the community (see how onedrive for businesses is evolving at the moment).