# Office 2016 Advanced Setup

Tags: installation, windows-10, microsoft-office-2016

I just started the Office 2016 Setup/Installation on my Windows 10 PC. The installation worked fine and started automatically showing only this dialog:

[image]

But there are no additional settings possible! I need to choose which programs I want to install and also add additional tools that are often missing when doing a default installation.

**How can I change the Office Installation Settings?**

- Choose programs to install
- Add/Remove Office Tools
- (Maybe) Office installation directory

When I check after the installation in the the windows settings, the Office can only be uninstalled - no modifications available:

[image]

Comment: It also installs the 32-bit version by default, even if the OS is 64-bit.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can use the [Office 2016 Deployment Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49117) to [customize the setup](http://www.askvg.com/tip-customize-microsoft-office-click-to-run-c2r-setup-to-install-selected-programs-only/). Edit the `Configuration.xml` and add new `ExcludeApp ID` entries for features you don't want to have installed:

[image: Image of the XML file]

```html
<Configuration>
    <Add SourcePath="E:\Office\" OfficeClientEdition="64">
        <Product ID="O365ProPlusRetail">
            <Language ID="en-us" />
            <ExcludeApp ID="Access" />
            <ExcludeApp ID="Excel" />
            <ExcludeApp ID="Groove" />
            <ExcludeApp ID="InfoPath" />
            <ExcludeApp ID="Lync" />
            <ExcludeApp ID="OneNote" />
            <ExcludeApp ID="PowerPoint" />
            <ExcludeApp ID="Project" />
            <ExcludeApp ID="Publisher" />
            <ExcludeApp ID="SharePointDesigner" />
            <ExcludeApp ID="Visio" />
        </Product>
    </Add>
</Configuration>
```

Now run `setup.exe /download configuration.xml` to only download the requested features and install the customized office with `setup.exe /configure configuration.xml`

Comment: There is now an online editor to generate the XML: http://officedev.github.io/Office-IT-Pro-Deployment-Scripts/XmlEditor.html

Comment: @MetroSmurf nice find.

Comment: this is ridiculous microsoft :(

Comment: It would be neat to have this pasted in textual format, so that people can easily copy/paste it.

Comment: Plain text version of the image added. Slightly confused about the product ID for **office2016** which is spelled as **O365ProPlusRetail**.

Comment: Hmm, the command "setup.exe /download configuration.xml" just shows the /help list, though both are in the same directory.

Comment: @Kevin I Microsoft update the tool and the office installer. What do you see now in the help list? I don't use office so I can't test this.

Comment: I'm not using this directly myself, but I have seen one mention that the sample product ID is incorrect for Office2016 and should be "ProPlusRetail" not "O365ProPlusRetail". Ref: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8ed89bf4-a772-4c60-86a8-30563467c1ee/using-configxml-for-installing-office-2016-makes-product-key-invalid?forum=Office2016setupdeploy

Comment: @fencepost All of the valid choices for that media are listed out in `\office\data\c3rfireflydata.xml` with the language choices on the DVD. What version you use is dependent on which type of key you have.

Comment: A convenience pastebin for those who want to install (Office2016 64bit) Excel and Word only: https://pastebin.com/eW7PgLuX

Comment: What worked for me was `.\setup.exe /download configuration.xml`

Answer (score 6):

I was originally going to add this as a comment to the excellent answer from @magicandre1981, however I couldn't get the comment to format in a readable state.

Please up vote the comments from @hennes and @MetroSmurf on that answer because those people found this info first and deserve recognition of that.

Once you download the config tool and build your custom-configuration.xml (I suggest renaming it so you know which config you are installing)

To have it work with the MSDN Media:

1. Make sure your config doesn't have a path set.
2. Ensure your product ID is as follows:
   `<Product ID="ProPlusRetail" PIDKEY="xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx">`
3. Suggest you also add `<Display AcceptEULA="TRUE">`
4. Extract the media to a folder (I used `Office2016`)
5. In `Office2016` replace default `setup.exe` (400KB) 
   with the deployment tool provided `setup.exe` (4.1MB)
6. Put your custom-configuration.xml in `Office2016` as well.
7. From an Administrative command prompt cd to `Office2016`
8. run `setup /configure custom-configfile.xml`
9. Profit.

Comment: this is the way

Answer (score 0):

[My question](https://superuser.com/questions/1525990/installing-outlook-2019-without-installing-all-of-office/1526896) was closed with a reference to this question as the original.  I'd like to add the answer to my question here because I believe that most people will find it easy to follow.  I'm also afraid that the valuable information will disappear along with the question.  The hard troubleshooting is captured [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_win10-mso_2016/installing-outlook-2019-without-installing-all-of/464de009-8718-4b15-82ac-58092a114827).

**To create Outlook 2019 profile without email, not connected to Microsoft, and thus not requiring sign-in to Microsoft,** run `Outlook.exe /PIM Profile-Name` to create an Outlook profile with no email.

This will not work, however, if you previously created an apparently no-email profile using `Control Panel -> Mail`.  That simply fails to do the job in Outlook 2019, though it worked in previous versions of Outlook.  Furthermore, the bad profile created will be the default profile, so Outlook will use it even if you subsequently ran `Outlook.exe /PIM Profile-Name`.  To undo this problem, you have to re-launch `Control Panel -> Mail` and one of the following:

- Delete the bad profile
- Set the option to prompt the user to choose a profile when Outlook starts
- Set the option to always use `Profile-Name`

Thanks to Karl Timmermans for this answer.