# Customise installation of Microsoft Office 2019

Tags: windows, installation, microsoft-office

When I ran `Setup.exe` on the Microsoft Office 2019 DVD, it automatically installed *all* the components with any user interaction - not even a single confirmation dialog.

How can I only install the components / programs that I wish to use?

Running `E:\Setup.exe /?` is useless.

I feel my computer is being force-infected with Microsoft's entire office ecosystem.

Is there a way of doing this without downloading another tool?

Comment: You have to use the [Office Deployment Tool](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/office2019/deploy).  This only works if your NOT using the click to run installer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 10 change Office 2016 installation directory](https://superuser.com/questions/1034222/windows-10-change-office-2016-installation-directory).  While the duplicate question was with regards to Office 2016 the answer is applicable to Office 2019

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Office 2016 Advanced Setup](https://superuser.com/questions/980032/office-2016-advanced-setup) . This question is about components not directory like the one that @Ramhound marked.