# Is there any way to reduce the size of MS Office install? I only need Word and Excel

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office, disk-space

[image: biggest storage hogs on my computer]

I'm close to capacity on this Windows 10 laptop and would like to reduce my biggest users.  Office 365 is the largest as you can see.  I only need Word and Excel.

Comment: Left click office.  Right click, select change, and deselect the components you don't want.  Then OK or apply.

Comment: check this: http://superuser.com/a/980264/174557